# Ruby `require': cannot load such file -- fcgi Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fastcgi, dreamhost

When trying to run a ruby script `ruby dispatch.fcgi` I get the error

```
/pathtorvm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- fcgi (LoadError)
from /pathtorvm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from dispatch.fcgi:8:in `<main>'
```

I am trying to follow Dreamhost's [Rvm](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rvm)/[Rails](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Ruby_on_Rails) install guide as well as multiple blog posts:

[Configuring Rails projects with FastCGI for Dreamhost shared hosting](http://danielstrunk.me/blog/2014/07/01/configuring-rails-projects-fastcgi-dreamhost-shared-hosting/)
[RAILS 4.0.0 WITH RUBY 2.0 ON A DREAMHOST SHARED SERVER](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/775)

I am using rvm => 1.26.11, ruby => 2.2.0, rails 4.2.2 successfully and have even tried ruby 2.0.0. I have tried to point all of my env_vars to the proper place but I am not 100% sure the $PATH var is setup properly.

I am using the bundler gem to install my gems and have `require 'fcgi'` inside of the Gemfile. Also I have removed the Gemfile.lock file and tried to run bundle install again. I thought maybe ruby-2.2.0 is causing problems but ruby-2.0.0 produced the same result & [RAILS 4.0.0 WITH RUBY 2.0 ON A DREAMHOST SHARED SERVER](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/775) clearly shows it working with ruby-2.0.0

`dispatch.fcgi`

```
#!/pathtorvm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby

# Dreamhost clears environment variables when calling dispatch.fcgi, set again
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
ENV['HOME'] ||= `echo ~`.strip
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')
require 'fcgi'
require '/pathtoapplication'sfile/config/boot.rb'
require '/pathtoapplication'sfile/config/environment.rb'

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
        def initialize(app)
                @app = app
        end

        def call(env)
                env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
            parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
            env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
            env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
            @app.call(env)
        end
end

#Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(ApplicationNamefoundin~../config/application.rb::Application)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `load`instead of `require` for the .rb files?

Comment: trying that gives dispatch.fcgi:8:in `load': cannot load such file -- fcgi (LoadError)
 from dispatch.fcgi:8:in \`<main>'

Comment: It sounds very stupid, but... It seems that there is a problem with the `.rb` file's path.

If `boot.rb` and `environment.rb` are in a folder at the same place where are your script, try using `./config/yourrbfilehere.rb` as path, with `load`.

Good luck.

Comment: no actually that is exactly what I was thinking

Comment: Ok, forgive me this stupid assumption: Did you try to install gem `fcgi`? Do you have it in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @AlexeyShein yes it is in my Gemfile and yes I have tried `gem install fcgi`

Comment: Have you tried:

`require 'rubygems'`
`require 'fcgi'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because I am using rvm. In `dispatch.fcgi`

```
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')
```

should be instead (notice /gems/ not /.gems/ -it will default to Dreamhost's ruby instead of my custom install)

```
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0')
```

Thanks [Dreamhost](https://www.dreamhost.com/) for the help

Answer (score 0):

The above actually did not help me at all. I had to add this:

```
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths
require 'fcgi'
```